# Fixed point set of orthogonal Transformation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, reflection

I need some help with this problem.

> Let $g$ be an element of the orthogonal group and $s$ a  reflection. Then the dimension of the fixed point set of $g$ and $gs$ differ by $\pm 1$. 
>   Since that lead to confusion, I mean 
>   $ \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}(1-gs))=
> \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}(1-g)) \pm 1$

Actually I only need this result in the special case of a finite reflection group defined by a root system. Does anyone have an idea? And it does not simply follow from the deletion condition.

Comment: Whatdo you mean with differ by $\pm1$? The fixpoint sets are always symmetric to the origin. And if $g$ is the identity, the fixpoint set of $g$ is the whole space, that of $gs$ is a hyperplane.

Comment: The determinant perhaps?